# Populating attribute field with Python function using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I'm working with PyQgis in version 2.18 and have a number of coordinates in WGS84 (decimal degrees) that I would like to convert to degrees, minutes, seconds (DMS) programmatically. I began by writing a Python function as follows:

```
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from qgis.core import * 
from qgis.gui import * 
import math


layer = iface.activeLayer()

#creating my new dms fields called 'LONGITUDE' and 'LATITUDE'
myField_1 = QgsField( 'LONGITUDE', QVariant.String)

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([myField_1])
layer.updateFields()

fed = layer.fieldNameIndex('LONGITUDE')

myField_2 = QgsField( 'LATITUDE', QVariant.String)

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([myField_2])
layer.updateFields()

det = layer.fieldNameIndex('LATITUDE')

#creating the function
def dd2dms(longitude, latitude):
    layer.commitChanges()
    split_degx = math.modf(longitude)
    degrees_x = int(split_degx[1])
    minutes_x = abs(int(math.modf(split_degx[0] * 60)[1]))
    seconds_x = abs(round(math.modf(split_degx[0] * 60)[0] * 60,2))

    # repeat for latitude
    split_degy = math.modf(latitude)
    degrees_y = int(split_degy[1])
    minutes_y = abs(int(math.modf(split_degy[0] * 60)[1]))
    seconds_y = abs(round(math.modf(split_degy[0] * 60)[0] * 60,2))

    # account for E/W & N/S
    if degrees_x <= 0:
        EorW = "W"
    else:
        EorW = "E"

    if degrees_y <= 0:
        NorS = "S"
    else:
        NorS = "N"

    # abs() remove negative from degrees, was only needed for if-else above
    print "\t" + str(abs(degrees_x)) + u"\u00b0 " + str(minutes_x) + "' " + str(seconds_x) + "\" " + EorW
    print "\t" + str(abs(degrees_y)) + u"\u00b0 " + str(minutes_y) + "' " + str(seconds_y) + "\" " + NorS



features = layer.getFeatures()

layer.startEditing()

#
for feat in features:
    name_1 = feat['LAT']
    name_2 = feat['LONG']
    feat[fed] = dd2dms(name_2, 0)
    feat[det] = dd2dms(0, name_1)
    layer.updateFeature(feat)

layer.commitChanges()
iface.vectorLayerTools().stopEditing(layer)
```

LAT and LONG are the names of the fields which I'd like to convert to DMS. The problem I'm facing now is that, when I run the script, the changes occur only on the Python console, but not in the attribute table. 
[image: values not appearing]
[image: python console results]

I would like to know why my attribute table is not getting populated when I run the script.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see is that the result of your function is two print statements which will just be printed to the console. In order to use those values you need to *return* them from your function.

I no longer use QGIS 2.18 and I have not tested this, but I would try something like this.

at the end of your function:

```py
x = "\t" + str(abs(degrees_x)) + u"\u00b0 " + str(minutes_x) + "' " + str(seconds_x) + "\" " + EorW
y = "\t" + str(abs(degrees_y)) + u"\u00b0 " + str(minutes_y) + "' " + str(seconds_y) + "\" " + NorS
return x, y
```

Then:

*Edit 1: Based on comments below- let's try working with the layer data provider.

```py
for feat in features:
    name_1 = feat['LAT']
    name_2 = feat['LONG']
    x_dms, y_dms = dd2dms(name_2, name_1) #unpack return values
    atts = {fed: str(x_dms), det: str(y_dms)}
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feat.id(): atts})

layer.commitChanges()
```

*Edit 2: You should also **remove** the `layer.commitChanges()` call from inside your function. You only need to call it **once** at the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your answer, but after trying it out, it still only populates the console and not the attribute table

Comment: No problem @GeomaSmart, I have updated my answer, using a different method of updating feature attributes. Hopefully this will work.